# xrandr and multiple displays

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, xrandr

So I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.  I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop and want to attach another monitor.  The native laptop display is running at 1366x768 and my monitor is running at 1440 x 900.  I have them positioned how I want them using xrandr, my problem is I can't stop the desktop on my monitor from panning across the native display when I move the mouse to that side.  Also when i try to maximize a window it spreads it across both displays making it extremely difficult to read.  Do I need both monitors running the same resolution?  I also tried switching the panning and panning borders with xrandr but nothing seems to be sticking.  Here's my xrandr details

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2806 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm panning 2806x900+0+0
1440x900       59.9*+
1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
1280x960       60.0  
1152x720       60.0  
1024x768       75.0     60.0  
800x600        75.0     60.3  
640x480        75.0     59.9  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+1440+0 256mm x 144mm
1366x768       60.0*+
1360x768       59.8     60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3     56.2  
640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected
VIRTUAL1 disconnected
1024x768 (0x2bc)   65.0MHz
    h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
800x600 (0x2be)   40.0MHz
    h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
640x480 (0x2c0)   25.2MHz
    h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
    v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
```

The external monitor is HDMI-0 and the laptop display is LVDS1.  The laptop has a nVidia 540M GPU as well as an integrated GPU.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you still facing this problem? I faced same thing along time ago but I forget which desktop manager if it was gdm or lightdm. Seems a bug.

Comment: Multiple directives in a single xandr invocation are not always reliable.

Comment: The solution is to change panning in `nvidia-settings`, same can be done on `xrandr --output HDMI-0 ... --panning 1440x900`